# Why do I lose points, if the person asking the question has withdrawn his account or deleted the question?

Tags: discussion

Many times, it happens that we answer a question correctly. But the user is quick to delete the question when it has been answered in comments. So instead of waiting for it to be posted as an answer, he either deletes the question quickly or removes his account if he is getting downvoted. What about the guy who took time to answer the question and still gets nothing in return :(

Comment: More so , there have been instances when i take the conversation to chats and end up with just a thanks .

Comment: Becoming attached to reputation advancement can get you really frustrated. I would suggest that you do not pay much attention to the reputation system. Helping and getting help is the most important part here.

Comment: I agree but when someone goes out of their way to help somebody else they barely know, 10 points is the least they could expect .

Comment: If an answer has received an upvote, the user can no longer delete their question themselves. 

The only way a question with upvoted answers can be deleted is through a moderator, or three experienced users with delete-vote rights. In which case it may well have been of poor quality, and Łukasz's advice applies.

Answer (score 4):

The user has no interest in deleting their own questions, with the exception when some questions was posted too fast and wasn't really a good question. Some new users, who ask very poor questions, may delete them because they are scared of downvotes, but in reality they are making things worse (having a lot of deleted question is risking a ban).

But the question can be removed by moderators if it's of very poor quality.

The solution: don't answer poor quality questions. It may be tempting because it looks like an easy rep, but it's a legitimate reason why you don't keep that rep if the question is removed: to discourage users from answering something, that simply doesn't belong here.

If you suspect the user removed the question because it was an assignment and he was cheating posting here, flag mods or feel free to write here.

Comment: "*If you suspect the user removed the answer*" - you probably meant *question* instead :)